# Is an AlphaMaskFilter correct in this case?

Tags: createjs

I am trying to use an alppha mask filter to apply a texture to a canvas element but cannot seem to get things to work.  I have a base image which is a flat white color and to which I want to apply a color filter at runtime based on a users selection for example:

```
  bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
  bitmap.filters = [
    new createjs.ColorFilter(0,0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 120, 0)
  ];
  bitmap.cache(0, 0, 500, 500, 2);
```

I then want to use a second image which is a texture png that will add various shading texture to that first one. Looking over the docs it would seem that I need to use an AlphaMaskFilter but that does not seem to work and nothing is rendered onto the canvas. For example:

```
  //filterImage contains the transparent image which has a shaded texture
  var bitmap2 = new createjs.Bitmap(filterImage);
  bitmap2.cache(0, 0, 500, 500, 2);
  var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
  bitmap.filters = [
    new createjs.ColorFilter(0,0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 120, 0),
    new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(bitmap2.cacheCanvas)
  ];
  bitmap.cache(0, 0, 500, 500, 2);
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction here or if I am trying to do something which is just not possible using that filter.

Comment: It seems to work for me - are all your images loaded? Here is a quick demo https://jsfiddle.net/cbfa4gvs/ -- Note that the mask image will just use the alpha channel, and its texture won't matter.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Looking at the behavior in your example, it seems that the ColorMatrix filter is actually what I am looking for in this case to adjust the base color of my image.  I tried to adjust your fiddle so my base textured white image should have that color applied to it but the result was to send the entire image to white. Am I missing something there?  My modified fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/andrewmrutter/hbmk15zw/16/  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think a ColorMatrix is what you want, since your image has no color in it. Instead, try using a Color filter. Here is an example that removes the red and green, leaving it blue: https://jsfiddle.net/mdv7L4e5/

Comment: You rock! That is exactly what  I was looking for - thanks